# Can we fix position of selected tab?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want to implement tabs with `TabLayout` but in a different way. What I want is, my tabs should be scrollable but I want to fix the position of the selected tab to be at middle. So far, I have found that we can have fixed tabs or scrollable tabs but nothing about fixing position of selected tab. Is this possible?

Comment: Well, I searched this also a lot. It cannot be done.

Comment: @sunlover3 Do you have any valid source. I just want to confirm.

Comment: I searched the documentation from Android, also the whole stack overflow, google. Nothing. :( Maybe you can send an email to the google developers and check an official opinion.

Comment: what do u mean? DO you want chrome like draggable tabs ?

Comment: @varunkr Not draggable. I want to fix the position of selected tab to be at center. At present, Selected tab move its position. I don't want that. I want to move tabs only but selection bar should stay at center

Comment: Can I know the reason why this question is down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just came across this library [SmartTabLayout](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout) and this is exactly what I wanted. Posting it here, in case anyone else need it in future.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you, you can generate it with a simple TabLayout.

The xml (scrollable tabMode)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your Activity - init page adapter with a simple adapter - here i call it PagerAdapter.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TestFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TestFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new TestFragment(), "THREE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TestFragment(), "FOUR");
        adapter.addFragment(new TestFragment(), "FIVE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TestFragment(), "SIX");
        adapter.addFragment(new TestFragment(), "SEVEN");
        adapter.addFragment(new TestFragment(), "EIGHT");
        adapter.addFragment(new TestFragment(), "NINE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TestFragment(), "TEN");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
```

As you can see here, if "SEVEN" tab is selected, its in the middle.
[image: Sample tablayout]

Comment: I have used this implementation, but when you swipe tabs, selector also moves with it.

Comment: Aren't you seeing the "SEVEN" tab in the middle ?

Comment: Even if you swipe to tab "nine", your selector will move to end. So, No! this is not what I want

Comment: You want to add "fake" margin right to nine so it'll look in the middle ?

Comment: Look the point is, I don't want my selector to move along swipe. it should be at a fixed position i.e at center. I think my point is clear in the question

Comment: sure i read it, its just isn't really clear. 
just trying to help

Comment: i have an idea of how to solve your issue, just need few moments